# How to split this text into columns

Tags: php

I have following text which I get as an output of a shell command.

```
c1     abc      def
c2     ghijk    lm
c30    a123     do390x
389    "a b c"  "my code" // spaced words
```

**EDIT: Now we have spaced words as well...**

The number of spaces are variable (no TABs). 
I want to convert this text into a 2D array. As shown under:

```
array(
   [0] => array(c1, abc, def),
   [1] => array(c2, ghijk, lm),
   [1] => array(c3, a123, do390x),
   [1] => array(389, a b c, my code),
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it data in TSV format?

Comment: explode on newline character then walk the resultant array and split on one or more spaces

Comment: No this is space separated

Comment: Is this data currently a string in a php variable? @MarkBaker 's comment pretty much describes the solution

Comment: `preg_split('/\s+/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clever nearly one-liner that should do the job:

```
$result = array_map(function($line) { 
    return preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
}, explode("\n", $text));
```

First `explode()` the `$text` to separate lines, then `preg_split()` it by spaces.

Comment: I think you will need to clean the line breaks.. `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );`

Comment: If it was on Windows, then I'd split on `\r\n`, but with the input given in the question the answer in current state is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the content in the columns has spaces you might want to use preg_split with double spaces.

`preg_split('/\s\s+/', $line);`

Comment: `\s+` is sufficient, see my answer.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk If any of the columns had a space in the value it would split on that too. eg if `c30    a123     do390x` was like this `c30    a123     do 390x` it would split in to 4 items rather than 3. note: There is double spacing in those examples it's just not coming out in the rendered code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm get result from a .txt for example):

```
$file = fopen("tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
$all = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $all[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

$result = array();
foreach ($all as $value) {

    $line = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value));
    $lineArray = explode(' ', $line);

    array_push($result, $lineArray);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```